# need help optimizing laravel complex query

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, optimization, eloquent

Laravel code:

```
        $posts = array();
        $allPosts = DB::table('post_categories')
                ->Join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_categories.posts_id')
                ->select('posts.title','posts.id','posts.body','posts.created_at')
                ->where('post_categories.categories_id','!=',5)
                ->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')
                ->get();
                
        foreach ($allPosts as $post){
            $categories = DB::table('post_categories')
                ->Join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'post_categories.categories_id')
                ->select('categories.name','categories.id')
                ->where('post_categories.posts_id','=',$post->id)
                ->get();
            $post->categories = $categories;
            array_push($posts,$post);
        }
```

Model relations:
**Posts** 1 - m **post_categories** m - 1 **categories**

first query is used fetch posts without category number 5
second is used to fetch categories in a post.

problem is i have a n+1 query due to the for loop.
so i was wondering if there was a better way to do this without the for loop

debugbar result:
[screenshot from debugbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvZjv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_categories` looks like a many:many mapping table.  If so follow the indexing advice in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Also, `posts` needs `INDEX(created_at)`.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`